# Unable to pull docker image, getting 'remote error: access denied'

Tags: docker, centos6.5

I'm trying to check the installation `docker pull hello-world`

But getting the following error:

```
Pulling repository hello-world
Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images: remote error: access denied
```

I have CentOS 6.5

Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d/1.7.1

I'm in a corporate network but `curl https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images` forks fine.

What might be the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

I got this error while I was trying to pull `mongodb` image instead of `mongo`.

So make sure image name is correct. The very same error message happens on both `run` and `pull` commands.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. Also make sure you add the correct tag/ version.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem & error on the host working via proxy.

In essence - if you are behind an HTTP proxy server, you will need to add proxy configuration in the Docker systemd service file.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/

(See at "HTTP proxy" section).

This helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add your user in docker group

https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/#/create-a-docker-group

Otherwise, you should execute docker command with sudo before

```
docker pull hello-world
```

Comment: I didn't see the part with proxy, sorry. I had also same issue, docker don't care System proxy already configurés. You have to configuré docker. Hère is à link about that. https://crondev.com/running-docker-behind-proxy/

Comment: thanks, Thibaut, with setting up proxy it's working now